# Convert a floating point to an integer with truncation instead of rounding using the x87 FPU

Tags: assembly, nasm, x87

The [*FISTP* instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_98.html) changes 0.75 to 1 (because of rounding)

I want 0.75 to turn into 0, not 1.

Is there an alternative to *FIST*/*FISTP* that truncates instead of rounds?

Comment: If you read the page you linked, you can see it says: _according to the rounding mode specified by the RC field of the FPU control word._ So obviously you need to change that. You might also be interested in section _4.8.4 Rounding_ in the _Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 1: Basic Architecture_.

Comment: Yes, I know it shouldn't be FISTP already, my question was if there is a similar function that truncates instead of rounds(Edited my question for clarity now)

Comment: Okay, go back and read it again. There is nothing wrong with `FISTP`, but you need to change the rounding mode. Yes, truncating **is** one of the modes. Also read the manual section I pointed you to.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can use SSE, there is a _CVTTSS2SI--Convert with Truncation_ instruction.

Comment: I can't use SSE. So to change the rounding mode, I think I would use FLDCW http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FLDCW.html   Its not very clear on how this works though?

Comment: Try `fisttp` if you have a Pentium IV or newer.

Comment: @fuz haha that exists too. Missed that. Good old FPU.

Comment: fisttp worked, thank you! at least I understand a little bit more on how floating points work in NASm by trying the other method hahaha

Comment: alright will do

Comment: If you can't use SSE, why `fisttp` did work for you? (just curious)

Answer (score 8):

You truly have a plethora of options here:

1. If you're using **SSE2** instructions anyway, then you can use the SSE2 instructions for converting a floating-point value to an integer value with truncation. [Peter Cordes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112846/366904) discusses this approach. **[`CVTTSD2SI`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_66.html)** is the scalar version, and **[`CVTTPD2DQ`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_63.html)** is the packed/vector version.

   If you're targeting x86-64, SSE2 will *always* be available, and this is what you *should* be using for all floating-point operations. The x87 FPU is completely obsolete on x86-64.

   If you're targeting x86-32 processors prior to the Pentium 4 or Athlon 64, then SSE2 instructions will not be available. In that case, **SSE** instructions may still be available (SSE is supported by Pentium 3, Athlon XP, and later). SSE supports only *single-precision* floating-point operations, so if you don't need the precision, you can use **[`CVTTSS2SI`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_67.html)** (scalar) or **[`CVTTPS2DQ`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_64.html)** (packed/vector). Unfortunately, you often need the precision; see below for a better workaround.
2. If **SSE3** instructions are available (Pentium 4 Prescott, certain Athlon 64s, and later), then you can use the **[`FISTTP`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_99.html)** instruction, which is like `FISTP`, except that it always truncates, regardless of the current rounding mode. This is the solution that [fuz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112477/366904) presents.

   This is a very good solution if you are already using the x87 FPU, but is of limited applicability because if you're targeting chips that support SSE3, they necessarily support SSE2, and therefore you should be using SSE instructions to do all floating-point manipulation. The only exception is if you *really* need the extended 80-bit precision offered by the x87 FPU for your intermediate calculations (SSE2 is limited to 64-bit double-precision).
3. If you are stuck on legacy x86-32 processors and using the **x87 FPU** without SSE, you're still not out of options. There are a couple of **fast bit-twiddling methods**. These were not my original innovations—the code is scattered around the Internet various places, I just collated and tweaked them slightly, so I cannot take full credit nor can I cite a particular source. [Here is one such source](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/floattoint.txt).

   For single-precision floating-point values, the entire bit representation fits into a 32-bit register, so the implementation is straightforward (this assumes that the floating-point value to be truncated is at the top of the x87 FPU stack):

   ```
   ; Retrieve the bit representation of the original floating-point value.
   push  eax
   fst   DWORD PTR [esp]
   mov   eax, DWORD PTR [esp]

   ; Twiddle those raw bits.
   and   eax, 080000000H
   xor   eax, 0BEFFFFFFH

   ; Store those manipulated bits back in memory, since we can't load        
   ; directly from a register to the x87 FPU stack.
   mov   DWORD PTR [esp], eax

   ; Add the modified value to the original value at the top of the stack.
   fadd  DWORD PTR [esp]

   ; Round the adjusted floating-point value to an integer.
   ; (Our bit manipulation ensures that this will always truncate,
   ; regardless of the current rounding mode.)
   fistp DWORD PTR [esp]

   ; ... do something with the result in ESP

   pop   eax
   ```

   An alternative implementation uses a static array of "adjustment" values, which we index into based on the "signedness" of the original floating-point value. This is basically what a naïve "truncate" function written in C would do, except that this does it branchlessly:

   ```
   const uint32_t kSingleAdjustments[2] = { 0xBEFFFFFF,  /* -0.49999997f */
                                            0x3EFFFFFF   /* +0.49999997f */ };
   ```

   ```
   ; Retrieve the bit representation of the floating-point value.
   push  eax
   fst   DWORD PTR [esp]
   mov   eax, DWORD PTR [esp]

   ; Isolate the sign bit.
   shr   eax, 31

   ; Use the sign bit as an index into the array of values to add the appropriate
   ; adjustment value to the original floating-point value at the top of the stack.
   ; (NOTE: This syntax is for MSVC's inline asm; translate as necessary.)
   fadd  DWORD PTR [kSingleAdjustments + (eax * TYPE kSingleAdjustments)]

   ; Round the adjusted floating-point value to an integer.
   ; (Our adjustment ensures that it will be truncated, regardless of rounding mode.)
   fistp DWORD PTR [esp]

   ; ... do something with the result in ESP

   pop   eax
   ```

   My benchmarks suggest that the second variant is faster on Intel processors, but slower on AMD (specifically, Athlon XP and Athlon 64). I ultimately settled on approach #2 for my library, especially since I re-use the "adjustment" values to implement other types of fast rounding.

   Note that the final [`FISTP`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_98.html) instruction supports both `m32` and `m64` operands, so if you want to truncate to a 64-bit integer for greater precision, that is possible. Just remember to allocate twice as much space on the stack, and then use `fistp QWORD PTR, [esp]` instead of `fistp DWORD PTR, [esp]`.

   I realize that this all looks very complicated, but *this really is significantly faster* than adjusting the rounding mode, doing the rounding, and setting the rounding mode back. I have benchmarked it extensively on a variety of processors, and in a variety of code paths, and *never* found it to be slower. But I use it in C code, where the compiler is required by the standard to emit code that restores the rounding mode. **If you're writing assembly by hand, and you need truncation, just switch the FPU's rounding mode to "truncate" once and leave it at that.**

   There is a double-precision version of this bit-twiddling code, too. The key is realizing that the sign bit lies in the upper 32 bits of a 64-bit double, so you still only need a single 32-bit register.

   However, the double-precision version is *not bug-free*! A floating-point value that is extremely close to a whole number will be rounded up to the nearest whole number, instead of being truncated (*e.g.*, 4.99999977 is erroneously rounded to 5, instead of being truncated to 4). Someone smarter than me and with more time to play around with this may come up with a way to fix this, but I'm satisfied with the accuracy of this in most cases, especially given the massive speed improvements.

   ```
   const uint64_t kDoubleAdjustments[2] = { 0xBFDFFFFF00000000,
                                            0x3FDFFFFF00000000 };
   ```

   ```
   sub   esp, 8
   fst   QWORD PTR [esp]
   mov   eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]   ; we only need the upper 32 bits

   shr   eax, 31
   fadd  QWORD PTR [kDoubleAdjustments + (eax * TYPE kDoubleAdjustments)]

   fistp DWORD PTR [esp]

   ; ... do something with the result in ESP

   add   esp, 8
   ```

Answer (score 4):

The [SSE3 instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE3) also introduced the `fisttp` instruction. It works like the `fistp` instruction, which can store a floating-point number as a 32-bit integer (popping the stack in the process), except that it always *truncates* the value, regardless of the current rounding mode.

Here is an example of how to use that:

```
FLD    QWORD PTR [esi] ; load 64 bit floating point number
FISTTP DWORD PTR [edi] ; truncate and store as 32 bit integer
```

or in AT&T-syntax:

```
fldl    (%esi)
fisttpl (%edi)
```

If you do not have a processor that supports SSE3, you can reach similar results with the `fistp` instruction after making sure the rounding mode is set to “truncate.”

```
sub    esp,0x4               ; make space for the control word
fstcw  WORD PTR [esp]        ; store the FPU control word
fstcw  WORD PTR [esp+0x2]    ; store another copy
or     WORD PTR [esp],0x0c00 ; set rounding mode to "truncate"
fldcw  WORD PTR [esp]        ; load updated control word
fld    QWORD PTR [esi]       ; load floating point number
fistp  WORD PTR [edi]        ; truncate to integer
fldcw  WORD PTR [esp+0x2]    ; restore control word
```

or in AT&T-syntax:

```
sub $4,%esp
fstcw (%esp)
fstcw 2(%esp)
orw $0x0c00,(%esp)
fldcw (%esp)
fldl (%esi) 
fistp (%edi)
fldcw 2(%esp)
```

If your code is not going to run on an 80286 or older, you might want to use `fnstcw` instead of `fstcw`  to save one byte per instruction at the expense of the code possibly not working on a real 8087.

Comment: FISTTP is part of SSE3.  So it was new with P4, just pointing out that there's no special feature-bit for it separate from SSE3, and that AMD CPUs much more recent than P4 lack it.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for that piece of information!

Comment: Peter is right, FISTTP is part of SSE3, but that means it is *not* available on *all* Pentium 4s. SSE3 was specifically introduced with Prescott, which was about halfway through the lifetime of the P4. I've updated your answer accordingly, since Peter's and my pedantry shouldn't have to disrupt your workflow. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: oh right, first-gen P4 introduced SSE2.  Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have to use mostly-obsolete x87 in the first place, then all the SSE/SSE2 conversion instructions (scalar and packed) have a truncating version that lets you (and C compilers) efficiently implement C semantics without changing the rounding mode.

e.g. [CVTSD2SI](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTSD2SI.html) vs. [CVTTSD2SI](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTTSD2SI.html),
or [CVTPS2DQ](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTPS2DQ.html) vs. [CVTTPS2DQ](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTTPS2DQ.html), all requiring only SSE2.

[CVTTSS2SI](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTTSS2SI.html) only requires SSE.

(SSE2 added support for double-precision floats and integer vectors in XMM registers, so SSE1 only has scalar single-float to integer register, not packed float to packed-DWORD vector.)

Yes I know the OP said they can't use SSE, but this is the right answer for this question title, and will hopefully be useful to future searchers.